# Usando animate() jquery para animar a troca de divs de lugar em um quebra cabeça

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

https://fiddle.jshell.net/sLa0q4yh/

Esse exemplo acima, ainda não está totalmente funcional, a lógica do quebra cabeça é:

1 - Clicar em pelo menos duas divs (ou 2 pedaços do quebra cabeça) e assim as duas divs teriam que trocar de lugar usando animação.

2 - Pra isso ocorrer, coletei com o offset do jquery, a posição top e left, tanto da primeira e segunda peça do quebra cabeça clicado.

3 - Porem ao usar o animate() (para fazer a animação da troca de peças) nada está acontecendo, eles continuam no mesmo lugar.

O que pode ser feito nesse caso?

Grato

Comment: Cara, faltou o `cont++` em cima do seu primeiro `if`. Ele não está adicionando contador na variável, então nunca entra nos `ifs`.

Comment: E não vai funcionar com `position: relative`.

Comment: é verdade eu esqueci de transcrever essa parte, mas já atualizei,  porem a animação não está indo para o local certo ainda. Obrigado pela verificação do erro. https://fiddle.jshell.net/sLa0q4yh/1/

Comment: Não vai porquê está com `position: relative`. Veja, como fiz em `absolute`. https://fiddle.jshell.net/sLa0q4yh/3/, porém estoura tudo o layout.

Comment: Eu notei, está ficando em desordem total no container. O que você acha que pode ser feito ali ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho o melhor é pensar como objetos.
Exemplo um puzzle precisa de ter uma base e peças.

Seguindo a logica precisamos de fazer a base (position:relative) e as peças (position:absolute).

Assim criei a class de css bloco com a position relative e com z-index 2 para assim quando o cliente clicar estar a selecionar a base e não a peça.

A class peça passou para position absolute e z-index 1 para reforçar que fica por baixo da base.

Com essa mudança, existiu a necessidade de colocar as peças no tabuleiro.
Foi criada a função start.

A função liga foi criada para marcar a peça ao numero da base.

A função anda foi criada para mover a peça com o efeito desejado.

Exemplo.:
https://jsfiddle.net/sLa0q4yh/5/

Comment: Tiago muito grato pela colocação dos pontos e exemplos, vou buscar entender o algoritmo e volto a perguntar pra ti caso eu não consiga entender algum ponto. Obrigado.

Comment: @user31050 Conseguiu verificar o código? Necessita mais alguma descrição? A pergunta ainda continua aberta.

Comment: Sim está ok a resposta, sou novato por aqui, como posso fechar a pergunta?Grato

Comment: A explicação http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 3):

Para o teu código funcionar, as tuas `.pecas` têm que estar posicionadas  em `absolute` desde o inicio, caso contrario quando mudas a posição do elemento de `relative` para `absolute` ele ... faz coisas estranhas, como estás a ver.

```
$(function(){
var top = 10, left = 0;
var piecesPerLine = 4;

$('.pecas').each(function(key, ele) {
    key += 1;
    piecesPerLine--;
    $('.parte-'+key).css({left:left,top: top});
    left += 156;
    if (piecesPerLine === 0) {
        left = 0;
        top += 80;
        piecesPerLine = 4;
    }
});
});
```

Se adicionares isto ao inicio do teu script, o [script que têns funciona](https://fiddle.jshell.net/sLa0q4yh/4/).
Básicamente, o que esta função está a fazer é a posicionar absolutamente os elementos por linhas. é de notar que mudei o css das `.pecas` para estar `position: absolute` de inicio.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica e instrução MoshMage.